# DS1307 RTC initialization stop working in every power up

Tags: c, embedded

I am initialized DS1307 RTC for 1hz square wave output for my project.

But I facing issue in every power up DS1307 stop working.

```
//--------------------- RTC 1307 initialisation  --------------------------------
 void rtc_init(void)
 {
  EA = 0;
  I2C_start();
  I2C_Master_Wait();
  I2DAT = 0xD0;
  //I2C_Master_Wait();
  //I2DAT = 0x00;
  I2C_Master_Wait();
  I2DAT = 0x07;
  I2C_Master_Wait();
  I2DAT = 0x10;
  I2C_Master_Wait();
  //I2DAT = 0x00;
  //I2C_Master_Wait();
  //I2DAT = 0x00;
  //I2C_Master_Wait();

  I2C_stop();  
 }
```

Again its start working after commenting and uncommenting the lines which were commented in code.

That is if power down with commenting following lines.

```
EA = 0;
  I2C_start();
  I2C_Master_Wait();
  I2DAT = 0xD0;
  //I2C_Master_Wait();
  //I2DAT = 0x00;
  I2C_Master_Wait();
  I2DAT = 0x07;
  I2C_Master_Wait();
  I2DAT = 0x10;
  I2C_Master_Wait();
  //I2DAT = 0x00;
  //I2C_Master_Wait();
  //I2DAT = 0x00;
  //I2C_Master_Wait();

  I2C_stop();
```

After power up I have to uncomment these lines, then it starts working and vice versa.

I am failed to find out what is the issue with it.

Comment: During power up, there are impulsive transients on the power pin, which may affect the IC. What if you add a delay (like 100ms) at the beginning of init function?

Comment: @KenTsoi,tried with a delay(up to 500ms )also .